# Can't compare the first line of .txt file with a string

Tags: java

I want to send studentGrade array to "calculate" method to calculate the average of grades but if the first line of text file is parameter, I can't. When the "if" method running, it goes back to while loop, even though two strings are equal.

I've tried to change the first line of .txt, in case of there is a problem. But the result was the same. It never does compare if the wanted person is in the first line.

```
static int studentNumber = 0;
static String[] studentGrade;
static String studentName = "";

static void makeList(String name) {
    try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\new_1.txt")))) {
        boolean flag = true;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            flag = true;
            String studentLine = sc.nextLine();
            studentGrade = studentLine.split(",");
            studentName = studentGrade[0];
            if (studentName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                calculate(studentGrade);
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        System.out.println("Couldn't found!");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occured when the file was tried to opened.");
    }
}

static void calculate(String[] a) {
    int note1 = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
    int note2 = Integer.parseInt(a[2]);
    int note3 = Integer.parseInt(a[3]);
    double avg = Math.ceil((double)(note1 + note2 + note3) / 3);
    System.out.println(a[0] + "'s average is: " + (int)avg);
}
```

I expect the if case would be true and sent the array to "calculate" method. It does its job except the student is in the first line of .txt file. For example if user input is Michael, it says "Couldn't found!" but if the input is John, it gives its average.

```
//First lines of .txt file
Michael,70,90,20
John,90,80,60
Molly,60,30,50
```

Comment: why you mark flag false when you find name?

Comment: Why are you using a `Scanner` if you are just reading lines? Just read the line from the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: When I try your code, it returns the correct averages: 60, 77 and 47

Comment: It appears the code you are showing should work. Please provide MCVE (read help section to see what that is) and input which produces the wrong output.

Comment: I used breakpoints and examined the steps of the program. In if statement, values of either part is the same string. But it doesn't go into if statement, it just returns to while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a file with the values you are giving:

```
Michael,70,90,20
John,90,80,60
Molly,60,30,50
```

And when I try your code, it seems to work fine:

```
makeList("Michael");
makeList("John");
makeList("Molly");
```

return

```
60
77
47
```

My suspicion is that you have some kind of invisible character at the very beginning of your file, and that is what makes your equality fail. I encountered this kind of issue several time when parsing XML and the parser would complain that my file doesn't start with an XML tag.

Can you try to make a brand new file with these 3 lines and try your program again on this new file?

Comment: No, it didn't work. Interesting that the code works for you but it doesn't for me..

Comment: @tuna I am still suspecting the file because the code works fine

Comment: @tuna You can find the file I used here https://volafile.org/r/tzezpjvm
Download it (no copy paste) and have a try with it. If it does not work, I give up :)

Comment: yes it works! Thanks. But I wonder what was the issue. By the way, I realized if I edit the .txt file "Micheal" to "Michael Phelps", it doesn't work again. Can you help me with it too?

Comment: `Michael Phelps,70,90,20` also works for me, returns `Michael Phelps's average is: 60`. The invisible character is probably due to some copy/pasting. Could be a lot of things.

Comment: @tuna please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: It's interesting. When I add a blank line at the top of the text, it works too. But if the text starts immediately with a line of students, it doesn't work for the first one.

Comment: What if you remove Micheal's line form the original file so that John is the first line. then `makeList("John");` If that works then you definitely have an invisible character on the Micheal's line

Comment: No, it doesn't work too. Whatever on the first line, it doesn't work. It's about nexLine(), I guess..

Comment: But you said it works with the file I provided, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler and clearer way to do this:

```
 try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\new_1.txt")) {
    Optional<String[]> studentGradesOpt = 
          lines.map(line -> line.split(","))
               .filter(row -> row[0].equalsIgnoreCase(name))
               .findFirst();

    studentGradesOpt.ifPresent(grades -> calculate(grades));
    if (!studentGradesOpt.isPresent()) {
      System.out.println("Couldn't find student " + name);
    }                          
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I haven't studied lambda expressions yet. Sorry